# Keyboard layout messed up

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am running 18.04 and after booting my computer today my keyboard has seemingly out of the blue lost functionality.

I cannot type `n` or `b` as they return `m` and `v` respectively.

`space` becomes `enter`

`shift` seems to be permanently enabled

The entire bottom row (`ctrl` `super` `alt` `space` etc) seems to be nonfunctional or always on.

For this reason, I can't type periods (`>`) or commas or select to copy-paste.
Moreover, also cannot type numbers.

**Some of these issues persist when using onscreen keyboard.**

I tried few fixes but most questions on this topic seem to pertain to us|uk keyboard layouts and not having a functional keyboard making trial and error extremely difficult.

This could also be a hardware issue but I don't have a spare keyboard with which to test that and I just wanted to see if anyone else had a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

This indeed seems to be (one of the funniest questions I read in a while, and) a hardware issue. [Keyboards are made up of a matrix](https://www.dribin.org/dave/keyboard/one_html/). So when you say the entire bottom row is not functioning, this seems to me as the electronics in your keyboard are either broken or in some faulty state.

That being said, when you want to review your keyboard layouts, go to Settings → Region & Language and check what's listed under 'Input Sources'.